# Hola quiero estoy haciendo una API multi lenguaje. Estoy utilizando Pasport Laravel

Tags: laravel, passport, idioma

Hola estoy utilizando laravel con passport.

Ya tengo todo listo solo quiero que los mensajes de validaciones cambien según este seteado el lenguaje del usuario. Para esto tengo un Endpoint.

```
Route::post('switch-lang/{lang}', function ($lang) {
    \Session::put('locale', $lang);
    if (\Auth::guard('user_api')->check()) {
        $user = \Auth::guard('user_api')->user();
        $user->Idioma = $lang;
        $user->save();
    }
});
```

Esto setea el lenguaje, sin embargo cuando inicializa tengo un middleware que cambia el lenguaje al que se va a utilizar durante todas las peticiones del usuario.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LanguageApiMiddleware
{

    protected $languages = ['en', 'es'];
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale('en');

        if(Auth::guard('user_api')->check() 
            && 
         in_array(Auth::guard('user_api')->user()->lang, $this->languages))
            App::setLocale(Auth::guard('user_api')->user()->lang);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

El problema es que no funciona el middleware por que el idioma siempre es el que tiene laravel por defecto. No importa que haga el switch en el endponit

Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://dev.to/fadilxcoder/adding-multi-language-functionality-in-a-website-developed-in-laravel-4ech

Comment: Hola, tenemos una implementacion muy similar. El problema que tenia es que no tenia variables de sesión al estar utilizando passport para mi api. Sin embargo pase esta vairiable a la base de datos, ahora la seteo desde el facade de Auth::guard("user_api")->user()->lang; gracias por tu ayuda, vale mucho.